Using --fixup after PR merged with GitHub "rebase and merge" workflow
Suppose I have a repository which is using rebase and merge workflow to ensure a linear commit history. No changes allowed directly on main branch.
If I have some changes on branch-2 (commit-a and commit-b) which have been merged to main and there are more commits on main.
In the future I realise there is a bug in commit-b. I want to either fix the bug in the same commit or I want to rewrite the history on main so that my fixing-commit shows up after commit-b
So if I want to use --fixup

I will check out branch-2
I will make the changes required
git commit --fixup <hash-for-commit-b>
git rebase -i --autosquash <hash-for-commit-b>~1

Once I do this and force push my branch, GitHub does not let me rebase it to main by saying that there are conflicts.
Is there something else that I need to do or is this not possible?
I tried these steps on my repo.
In the above PR you can see that it is not letting me rebase and merge.


You have the "rebase + merge" workflow. The original branch-2 doesn't exist any longer, it has been rebased. Its commits have been rewritten. Also, you shouldn't rewrite published history (main), just create a regular bugfix commit to fix the mistake

I understand that I should not rewrite published history. But I wanted to know if there was a way I could do it?

You can, but you have to rebase main, not branch2. A different version of branch2 was already merged to main
